# How to transfer/clone data from one internal storage SD card to another?

Tags: external-sd, data-transfer, adoptable-storage

So I've been using a micro SD card as internal storage. It's getting full, so I'd like to transfer the data to another micro SD card.

I tried cloning it, but for whatever reason (I think it's got to do with the encryption that makes it internal storage) it doesn't work properly. I managed to format the new card as internal storage as well, and I've got a card reader that I can insert into my phone. The phone recognizes the new card as internal storage, but none of the file managers I've tried see all three storages *and* will let me move the data from one card to the other.

Is there any way to correctly transfer the data without losing anything? Or am I just kinda hosed?

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/142064/change-adopted-storage-to-a-larger-storage

Comment: create tarball archive (root required) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/222394